# How to perform Vector-Matrix Multiplication with BLAS ?

Tags: matrix, matrix-multiplication, blas

BLAS defines the GEMV (Matrix-Vector Multiplication) level-2 operation. How to use a BLAS Library to perform Vector-Matrix Multiplication ?

It's probably obvious, but I don't see how to use BLAS operation for this multiplication. I would have expected a GEVM operation.

Comment: transpose(x) . transpose(A) = A.x

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Matrix-Vector multiplication of a (M x N) Matrix with a (N x 1) Vector will result an (M x 1) Vector. In short `a*A(MxN)*X(Nx1) + b*Y(Mx1) -> Y(Mx1)`. Of course you can use `INCX` and `INCY` when your vector is included in a matrix.

In order to define a Vector-Matrix multiplication The Vector should be transposed. i.e. `a*X(1xM)*A(MxN) + b*Y(1xN) -> Y(1xN)`. Basically you do not have a vector but a single row matrix.

Starting from this point there are two possibilities.

Either use level-3 "GEMM"

```
?gemm(transa, transb, m, n, k, alpha, a, lda, b, ldb, beta, c, ldc)
```

using

```
?gemm('N', 'N', 1, N, M, a, X, 1, A, M, b, Y, 1)
```

Or do some more math. Considering that `(X*A)^T = A^T * X^T` the row matrix `X` is converted to vector X^T(MX1). Also `Y` transpose is vector `Y^T(Nx1)`. Of course memory-wise both `X` and `X^T` are store with the same way, sequentially. This means you can use again `GEMV` using transpose matrix `A`

```
?gemv('T', M, N, a, A, M, X, 1, b, Y, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the precise examples, it works well :)

Comment: I tried both. But `?gemm` is around 2~3 times faster than `?gemv`. Shouldn't `?gemv` always be faster than `?gemm`?